# How Do I get rid of the Crash(Low understanding) for using reactive approach

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am relatively new to reactive world , In My codebase I have decided to apply reactive philosophy in a very incremental way which is taking small step at a time . whit this motivation I have a changed a function this way

```
public List<Task> getFilteredTask() {
  return Observable.fromIterable(TaskDataSource.getAllTasks())
         .filter(task -> !task.isCompleted  && !task.getPriority>=1)       
         .sorted((task!, task2) ->  task.title.compareTo(task2.tilte)).toList().blockingFirst();
```

I Had to useBlockingX() operator my client recieves List for this time being . So I had to unwrap the **Single** Observable .

But I am getting exception after calling this ? Please Help me What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you attach the crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your Log messages , although I am pretty much sure You are getting this error as you possibly calling this method from MainThread . As You know long running operation supposed to be deferred off to Main Thread .

Second Thing I would Like to address is RxJava was created with Laziness in mind . Here you are violating it with Observable Creation with `Observable.fromIterable(TaskDataSource.getAllTasks())` as You can see `TaskDataSource.getAllTasks()` is getting called even before there is any observer subscribed to it . So I think with this modification you will get rid of the crash

```
public Observable<Task> getFilteredTask() { 
   return Observable.defer(() ->
       Observable.fromIterable(TaskDataSource.getAllTasks())).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .filter(task -> !task.isCompleted  && !task.getPriority>=1) 
    .sorted((task!, task2) ->  task.title.compareTo(task2.tilte)) 
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Further more I would like to say modify you'r calling client for accepting Observable instead of List . Because Using **BlockinX()** is strongly discouraged by Rx Community because Instead of Being data Pushed as It is ready you are pulling data and blocking the thread

Hope it will help